# PHP Remove size and face attributes only in font tag

Tags: php, fonts, attributes

How i can remove the size attribute and face attribute only in html font tag using PHP.

```
<font color="#ff0000" size="4" face="georgia"> text text again</font> 
again and again text <font color="#ff0000"> text text again </font>
```

by the way. im using wysiwyg editor thats why is in font tags and i only want to display the string without the size and face attribute.

Comment: don't use `<font>` tags. It's deprecated since forever... use `<span>` instead.

Comment: im using wysiwyg html editor and i want to display it without removing other attribute except in size and face attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[`<font>` tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.2) are deprecated. Use `<span>` instead.**

To answer your question: you can remove the attributes using DOMDocument:

```
$html = '<font color="#ff0000" size="4"> text </font>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('font') as $tag) {
    $tag->removeAttribute('size');
    $tag->removeAttribute('face');
}

echo $dom->saveHTML($tag);
```

Output:

```
<font color="#ff0000"> text </font>
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/129456)

Comment: +1, for the DOM and information regarding deprecation.

Comment: thank you for your code but i having a problem with this example:" <font color="#ff0000" size="4"> text ref </font> textagain again and again <font color="#ff0000" size="4"> text</font> " - base on your code it only display the string inside the font tags from the first font tags only and the rest are not display.  by the way im using wysiwyg html editor thats why is in font tag. sorry for my english im not a native english speaker.

Comment: @user3449752: Just change `$dom->saveHTML($tag);` to `$dom->saveHTML();`. See demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/859MKe

Comment: i have question. what if i want also in h1,h2 or span is it possible aside from font tag?

Comment: @user3449752: yes, repeat the same process. Or use an XPath expression. It's a different problem, so I suggest you ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: i have another question. what if i want to remove the face and size attribute in all tags like span, h1-h6 and etc.